# Instagram login video screencast

Tags: instagram-api

I am coding my app/website to work with Instagram, along with Twitter and Facebook. I saw that a video screencast is required to show:

> Please make sure that the video clearly shows how your application works, including any Instagram **login experience** and the usage of every permission you are requesting.

Does this mean it needs to have an Instagram login? We only offer login with Facebook, Twitter, or email accounts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The Instagram API requires authentication - specifically requests made on behalf of a user. Authenticated requests require an `access_token`. These tokens are unique to a user and should be stored securely."

- https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

I don't think you can make any Instagram API calls without supporting Instagram login.

Comment: Do you think it's required if we are searching public Instagram content on behalf of our user? vs. logging in on behalf of actual Instagram users?

Comment: How are you performing any action on behalf of your Instagram users without them logging in?  A link to the documentation is right there; I suggest you review it carefully.

Comment: we actually aren't performing any actions on behalf of instagram users, we are simply searching public photos. But thanks, we will read it again. :)